# ImageMagick Conversion from .ps to .png, run from python - invalid param

Tags: python, cmd, postscript, imagemagick-convert

I have been looking through some similar posts and through the ImageMagick page, but I cannot seem to find a reason for my issue:

**Note** I am using a windows machine.

I have a .ps image in a folder and it works when running with the command to convert it from the cmd: `convert saved.ps newsaved.png`

**However** when I try to execute it from my python script with the following code:

`args = ["convert","saved.ps newsave.png"]
 subprocess.Popen(args)
 #or this call(args)
 os.system("start newsave.png")`

The cmd window says that newsave.png is an invalid parameter. (The error message being: `Invalid parameter - newsave.png` in the cmd window, which then closes instantly)

Having the everything seperated by a comma in `args` has also not helped. `os.getcwd()` returns the current work directory as well, so I know I'm in the right dir. The error happens when the subprocess is called.

Comment: What if you use this `args = ['convert', 'saved.ps', 'newsave.png']` `subprocess.Popen(args)` ? Because that works fine for me if saved.ps is in the working directory.
You can print your current workdir with `import os`
`os.getcwd()` btw.

Comment: It looks like you are using Windows.  It might be that your attempt to run ImageMagick's `convert` command is actually running the Windows `convert` command, which attempts to convert a hard drive partition from FAT to NTFS format.  Trying making the first argument of `args` be the full path of the ImageMagick `convert` command.

Comment: when using it straight from the cmd it works fine, when trying to invoke it from python is when it causes issues.

Comment: The search paths might be different in those two cases.  Give it a shot.

Comment: how do I got about using the full path? my command-line skills are lacking a bit

Comment: looked around a bit, I don't think the issue is confusion b/w the two converts, but I will try and find the imagemagick `convert` path

Comment: Sorry, my Windows skills are lacking.  Find out where the executable command `convert` was installed when you installed ImageMagick.  In the meantime, here's a shot-in-the-dark possibility: try adding `shell=True` in the call to `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.Popen`.  I don't know if that will make a difference, and I don't have a Windows installation handy to test.

Comment: thanks, I will try that and play around with it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to add `shell=True` in order for the conversion to work properly.

`args = ["convert", "saved.ps", "newsave.png"]
 subprocess.call(args, shell=True)`

Thanks to [Warren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Make each command-line argument a separate element of `args`.  Also, use `subprocess.call` to ensure that the `convert` function has completed before you call `os.system("start newsave.png")`:

```
args = ["convert", "saved.ps", "newsave.png"]
rc = subprocess.call(args)
if rc != 0:
    print "rc =", rc
```

Comment: it still tells me that newsave.png is an invalid parameter

Comment: Strange.  It works for me (Python 2.7.10, imagemagick 6.8.3-3, Mac OS X).  Can you edit the question to include the *complete* error message?  Does the error occur in the call `subprocess.Popen(args)` or in `os.system("start newsave.png")`?  Also, it looks like you should use `subprocess.call` and not `subprocess.Popen`, to ensure that the `convert` command has finished before `os.system("start newsave.png")` is called.

Comment: I still get the error even without `os.system("start newsave.png")` and the entirety of the error message is: `Invalid parameter - newsave.png`, I will try using `subprocess.call` now and let you know how that goes

Comment: When you do, check the return value of `call`.

Comment: sorry if it's a silly question, but how do I do that? if it works with `print(subprocess.call(args))` then the output was 4?

Comment: See my edited answer.  It might not tell you anything new, but it is still a good practice. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93082/discussion-between-oliver-and-warren-weckesser).